# Case Sensitive username

Tags: users, login

Is craft's username field case sensitive when logging in?

I'm importing 80 users into the database and when emailing the users I want to be sure how this works so we don't hit issues when they all try to log in.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this locally on Craft3 and Craft2 and it seems that the username field is not case sensitive (e.g. `admin`, `ADMIN`, and `AdMiN` all worked equally as well for me).